# Apache deny access to images folder, but still able to display via <img> on site

Tags: apache2, security, database, access-control

I have an images folder on my site, let's call it `/images/` where I keep a lot of images.  I don't want anyone to have direct access to the images via the web, so I put a new directive in my Apache config that achieves this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/images/">
    Options Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

This is working, but it is blocking out ALL ACCESS, and I can't show the images anymore through my web pages.  I guess this makes sense.  So how do I selectively control access to these images?

Basically I only want to display certain images through certain webpages and to certain users.  What is best way to do this?  Do I need to save the images to the database?

Tim

Comment: That's a programming question, it belongs to stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

This is something that needs to be done in the code. You have to rewrite your code so for certain users the code will read the image from the local disk(rather then send it as an html  ellement) and send it directly to the html output. The next links might give some info on how to do this:

[How to retrieve image from server and display using json parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232076/how-to-retrieve-image-from-server-and-display-using-json-parsing)

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=168935

Comment: I understand all the technical stuff is done in code (which I already have finished) The problem is that the directive I showed above blocks out access, so even if I give the correct path the the <img> element, the server blocks access to the image files.  I need to block access so that all the users can't see the images by entering the links directly.  SO the code isn't the problem, the access control is the problem.

Comment: You still have access to these files if you get them using the code examples I've given the links to, since although you can't directly access these images via web, you still have access to them via your disk. So in this case you can make this work by adapting your code to get these files and then send them directly in the http response as shown.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to grant access to your images but not to the images directy from web, you can play with the roles and grant for example permissions for the images for an specific user, and use that user to go and read the images, also need to include an index file to dont allow users to list all the images at your directory.

Use `chown` to change the permissions on your files

Answer (score 0):

a very simple alternative is to add empty *index.html* in *images* folder so
`http://example.com/images/my-picture.png` returns my-picture.png
but
`http://example.com/images/` returns blank page !